# Retrieving the provider value gives null as its value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I have created a `provider` to pass down the values within the `WidgetTree`, but when I try to retrieve the value, it gives me `null` as its value.

Initializing the value for the `Provider`:

```
              GetCurrentCourse course = GetCurrentCourse();
              course.currentCourse(
                courseID: courseID,
                courseDocID: courseDocID,
              );
```

Below is the code related to the `Provider`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GetCurrentCourse extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? currentCourseID;
  String? currentCourseDocID;

  void currentCourse({courseID, courseDocID}) {
    this.currentCourseDocID = courseDocID;
    this.currentCourseID = courseID;
    print("Current Course ID is ${this.currentCourseID}");
    print("Current Course Doc ID is ${this.currentCourseDocID}");
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

When I print the values within the above `GetCurrentCourse` class. I do see the correct values getting printed.

Below is the code showcasing the `Provider` defined within the `main.dart` file as shown below:

```
        ChangeNotifierProvider<GetCurrentCourse>(
          create: (_) => GetCurrentCourse(),
        ),
```

Below is the code where I'm trying to consume the `GetCurrentCourse` Provider:

```
class CoursePageBody extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Printing Value of Course from Provider");
    print(Provider.of<GetCurrentCourse>(context).currentCourseDocID);
    .
    .
  }
 }
```

Now, when I try to access the value of the `Provider` and try to print it. It prints `null`.

What can I try to fix it?

Comment: Can you share where you inserted the provider?

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization code should be:

```dart
var courseProvider = Provider.of<GetCurrentCourse>(context, listen: false);
courseProvider.currentCourse(
  courseID: courseID,
  courseDocID: courseDocID,
);
```

And the widget that is going to access it should be wrapped in a `Consumer` that would look something like:

```dart
class CoursePageBody extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GetCurrentCourse>(
      builder: (context, courseProvider, child) {
       print("Printing Value of Course from Provider");
       print(courseProvider.currentCourseDocID);
       // rest of the code
     }
   );
  }
 }
```